# Strong parameters and POSTing: 'undefimed method permit for string'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a simple barebones CRUD application that lists a movie collection and lets you edit existing entries or add new ones.

`movie#new` displays a form with four fields:

- `text_field_tag(:title)`
- `text_field_tag(:genre)`
- `number_field_tag(:rating, min: 0, max: 10, step: 1)`
- `check_box_tag(:bluray)`

The form submits to `movie#create`, which reads:

```
Movie.create(params.require(:title).permit(:genre, :rating, :bluray))
redirect_to(index)
```

Here's the problem! Submitting the form lands me the error **undefined method 'permit' for 'Vertigo':String**.

On the error page, I can see that the parameters are posted as a hash, the way you'd expect:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"x55ibBjNoYCAfSNi3hNREvyIkMTMn7DTrI3YGqzCk0Hefvjx41vlYKDlNLSTsnNlH7cXTkXM1IUReJbKrCjI6g==",
 "title"=>"Vertigo",
 "genre"=>"Mystery",
 "rating"=>"9",
 "bluray"=>"0",
 "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

This one is stumping me, even after Googling the issue. Apparently the problem for some people is that rather than a params hash they get one big params string, but that doesn't seem to be happening here -- in the little REPL helpfully included on the error page, I can type `params[:title]` and get "Vertigo" back.

I am using Rails 4.2.0 and Ruby 2.0.0-x64 on Windows 8.1 (please don't hurt me), serving with WEBrick.

My form is

```
<%= form_tag(action: 'create') do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:title) %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:genre) %>
    <%= number_field_tag(:rating, min: 0, max: 10, step: 1) %>
    <%= check_box_tag(:bluray) %>
    <%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @RSB I've updated the post with the form code.

Comment: @GreenTriangle why did you create your form with `form_tag` instead of `form_for`?

Comment: @MarekLipka I'm not familiar with `form_for` yet.

Comment: @GreenTriangle so it's the perfect moment to get familiar with it.

Comment: I gave you the answer. Check if it works, since there will probably be some problem with routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have used `form_tag` instead of `form_for`, this should resolve your problem

In your movies controller

```
def new
  @movie = Movie.new
end

def create
  @movie = Movie.new(movie_params)
  @movie.save
end

def movie_params
  params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :genre, :rating, :bluray)
end
```

Your form should use `form_for`

```
<%= form_for @movie do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :genre %>
  <%= f.number_field :rating, min: 0, max: 10, step: 1 %>
  <%= f.check_box :bluray %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for this. That helps a lot. I do have some questions, though. How does Rails know where to submit the form if I don't specify the action? Is it just assuming that `#new`'s forms will submit to `#create`? And if I don't need to access a blank `Movie` instance while I'm rendering the `/movies/new` page, why do I have to create one? I thought `form_for` was more for modifying an existing object or when a form submitted to itself, this usage is a little confusing.

Comment: Yes, since @movie is an object of Movie model it will go to create action of Movies controller

Answer (score 1):

First thing, rebuild your form so it use `form_for`:

```
<%= form_for @movie do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :genre %>
  <%= f.number_field :rating, min: 0, max: 10, step: 1
  <%= f.check_box :bluray %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Then, in your controller:

```
Movie.create(params.require(:movie).permit(:title, :genre, :rating, :bluray))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, it's appreciated. I'm reading about `form_for` now. I do have an additional question: why does `require` take the name of the model itself as an argument? I thought, based on what I've read, that `require` was like `permit` only it would throw an exception if the specified attribute wasn't found. My thinking was that I *required* all movies in my database to have a title, but a rating and genre was optional.

Comment: @GreenTriangle It's because this is the name of the key in your params hash describing created model, by default. `require` is all different than `permit`, you use `require` on keys that holds another hash with params, like when you use `form_for`.